# Regex and Pandas Dataframe error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, pandas, regex, lambda, nlp

there!

I have a dataframe and I want to extract cellphone numbers.

```
VARIAVEL
Telefone:(11) 95262-7297
Celular:(31) 97250-8639
Não possui
```

Below is the code which I'm using to do it:

```
df['TELEFONE'] = df['VARIAVEL'].apply(lambda x: re.search('\(\d\d\)\s\d\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d', x).group(0) if pd.notnull(x) else x )
```

The erros which is returning is:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I know the error is because 'Não possui' returns no match, and due to it I can't use 'group(0)'.

How can I fix it? How can I apply regex and group(0) just on matched cases?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
df['TELEFONE'] = df['VARIAVEL'].str.extract(r'(\(\d{2}\)\s\d{5}-\d{4})', expand=False)
```

See a Pandas test:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'VARIAVEL':['(11) 95262-7297', '(31) 97250-8639', 'Não possui']})
df['TELEFONE'] = df['VARIAVEL'].str.extract(r'(\(\d{2}\)\s\d{5}-\d{4})', expand=False)
```

Output:

```py
>>> df
          VARIAVEL         TELEFONE
0  (11) 95262-7297  (11) 95262-7297
1  (31) 97250-8639  (31) 97250-8639
2       Não possui              NaN
```

If you need to *extract* a *multiple* matches, you would need a `Series.str.findall`:

```py
df['TELEFONE'] = df['VARIAVEL'].str.findall(r'\(\d{2}\)\s\d{5}-\d{4}').str.join(', ')
```

Comment: Hi, Wiktor. I forget to say, my column will not have just numbers. I just edited my ask. But i'm trying to use your solution.

Comment: @HernandesMatiasJunior Then `df['TELEFONE'] = df['VARIAVEL'].str.extract(r'(\(\d{2}\)\s\d{5}-\d{4})', expand=False)` is the solution for the updated question. I removed the `Series.str.contains` code.